# Can Laravel automatically switch between column = ? and column IS NULL depending on value?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, null

When building a complex SQL query for Laravel, using `?` as placeholders for parameters is great. However when the value is null, the SQL syntax needs to be changed from `= ?` to `IS NULL`. Plus, since the number of parameters is one less, I need to pass a different array.

To get it to work, I have written it like this, but there must be a better way:

```php
if ($cohortId === null) {
    // sql should be: column IS NULL
    $sqlCohortString = "IS NULL";
    $params = [
        Carbon::today()->subDays(90),
        // no cohort id here
    ];
} else {
    // sql should be: column = ?
    $sqlCohortString = "= ?";
    $params = [
        Carbon::today()->subDays(90),
        $cohortId
    ];
}

$query = "SELECT items.`name`,
        snapshots.`value`,
        snapshots.`taken_at`,
    FROM snapshots
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id, item_id
        FROM snapshots
        WHERE `taken_at` > ?
        AND snapshots.`cohort_id` $sqlCohortString
        GROUP BY item_id
    ) latest
    ON latest.`id` = snapshots.`id`
    INNER JOIN items
    ON items.`id` = snapshots.`item_id`
    ORDER by media_items.`slug` ASC
";

$chartData = DB::select($query, $params);
```

My question is: does Laravel have a way to detect null values and replace `?` more intelligently?

PS: The SQL is for a chart, so I need the single highest snapshot value for each item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`->when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) to create a conditional where clause:

```
$data = DB::table('table')
    ->when($cohortId === null, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereNull('cohort_id');
    }, function ($query) use ($cohortId) {
        // the "use" keyword provides access to "outer" variables
        return $query->where('cohort_id', '=', $cohortId);
    })
    ->where('taken_at', '>', $someDate)
    ->toSql();
```